# How to read CSV files with kafka?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I want to stream CSV files on spark with kafka.

All the files are saved on hdfs by another service, and I would like to read all the files using kafka. Something similar to what is done with spark streaming:

```
 val event1 = spark
   .readStream
   .schema(test_raw)
   .option("newFilesOnly", "true")
   .option("header", "true") 
   .option("sep", ",") 
   .csv(stream_path)
```

Comment: You can read CSV with Spark, then do whatever you want with it. Kafka is a message broker. It is used for Publishing/subscribing, backpressure and other communication purposes. There is no "CSV reading" with Kafka.

Comment: Thank you for the information,but what about the csv connector for kafka

Comment: Have you tried starting with `event1.writeStream.format("kafka")`?

Answer (score 0):

The connector you're looking for might be this one : https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir